# Two non-negative functions $\,f,g$, such that $\,f \not\in \mathcal O(g)$ and $ g \not\in \mathcal O(\,f)$

Tags: analysis, algorithms, computational-complexity

Show that there exist two non-negative functions $\,f,g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\,f \not\in \mathcal O(g)$ and $ g \not\in \mathcal O(\,f)$.

It would be easy two find two such functions for which one can also take negative values, but I can't seem to find two non-negative functions. Can anybody help please?

Comment: $f(n)=1/|\sin n|$, $g(n)=1/|\cos n|$.

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi very nice

Comment: Thanks, just wrote a more detailed answer.

Comment: Are you sure the case where you allow negative values is really easier? Remember that there's an absolute value in the definition...

Comment: Actually a negative-valued function would not make any difference because the $O$-notation only cares about boundedness, not about signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just choose
$$
f(n)=\frac{1}{|\sin n|}, \quad g(n)=\frac{1}{|\cos n|}.$$
You have that
$$
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}= |\textrm{cotg } n|,\quad \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=|\tan n|,
$$
and none of those are bounded.

Answer (score 5):

Consider
$$
f(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} n & \text{if} & n \,\,\text{odd}, \\
1 & \text{if} & n \,\,\text{even},
\end{array}\right.
$$
and
$$
g(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} 1 & \text{if} & n \,\,\text{odd}, \\
n & \text{if} & n \,\,\text{even}.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 2):

How about any functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying

$f(1) = 1$, $f(2)=0$, $g(1) = 0$, and $g(2)=1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(n) = n^2 \sin^2{an}, \qquad g(n) = n^2 \cos^2{an} $$
Then
$$ \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \tan^2{an}, \qquad \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = \cot^2{an}. $$
Choose $a = \pi/2$ for the most obvious problems.